# dojo on event handler not working for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I have a div element in my application, I am adding buttons in it, but only working last button event. The code is in [**`jsfiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/Eet65/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is using `innerHTML`, whenever you use it it wipes all the elements and events in the node and then recreates the nodes, witout your events.

you can use this instead of innerHTML:

```
dojo.create("button", { id: "hom", innerHTML:"hom"}, node);
```

this is your working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Eet65/1/).

Comment: @bookmarker: check my answer and the fiddle to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dojo >1.7 syntax, you can attach an event to a node like this, notice how [domConstruct.create](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-construct.html#create) returns a reference to the created node:

```
var test1 = function(){
   var parent = dom.byId('buttons');                   

   var test1 = domConstruct.create("button", {id:"test1", innerHTML:"test"}, parent); 

   on(test1, "click, keyup", function (event) {
      if (event.type === 'click' || (event.type === 'keyup' && event.keyCode === 13)) {
         console.log("test1 Button click")    
      }               
   });          
}
```